# Why did lagom throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.broker.TopicFactoryProvider?

Tags: lagom

A previous attempt to run an initial lagom service failed after getting help on [getting a service listening][1].

So, on this attempt, a maven project (usvcs) has only two modules (actor-api and actor-impl) and a single service call 'echo'.

```
public interface MAIActorsService extends Service {
  ServiceCall<NotUsed, String> echo(String s);
  @Override
  default Descriptor descriptor() {
    // @formatter:off
    return named("cmai_actors").withCalls(
            restCall(Method.GET, "/echo/:s", this::echo)
      ).withAutoAcl(true);
    // @formatter:on
  }
}
```

and the implementation is a stub that doesn't have an entity reference.

```
@Override
public ServiceCall<NotUsed, String> echo(String s) {
    return request -> {
        CompletableFuture<String> alreadyCompleted = CompletableFuture.completedFuture(s);
        try {
            alreadyCompleted.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return alreadyCompleted;
      };
}
```

running 'mvn lagom:runAll' throws and exception stating an **internal** lagom dsl class is not found.

```
$ mvn lagom:runAll
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] usvcs
[INFO] actor-api
[INFO] actor-impl
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building usvcs 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- lagom-maven-plugin:1.3.0-M1:runAll (default-cli) @ usvcs ---
[INFO] Starting Kafka
[INFO] Starting Cassandra
.[INFO] Did not find Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, defaulting to NIO.
.........[INFO] Using data-center name 'datacenter1' for DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy (if this is incorrect, please provide the correct datacenter name with DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy constructor)
[INFO] New Cassandra host /127.0.0.1:4000 added
[INFO] Cassandra server running at 127.0.0.1:4000
[INFO] Service locator is running at http://localhost:8000
[INFO] Service gateway is running at http://localhost:9000
No play.logger.configurator found: logging must be configured entirely by the application.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\lusp\maisvc\usvcs\actor-api\src\main\resources
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/lightbend/lagom/internal/javadsl/api/broker/TopicFactoryProvider
        at com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.registry.ServiceRegistryModule.configure(ServiceRegistryModule.scala:35)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule.configure(Modules.java:177)
        at com.google.inject.AbstractModule.configure(AbstractModule.java:62)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements$RecordingBinder.install(Elements.java:340)
        at com.google.inject.spi.Elements.getElements(Elements.java:110)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:138)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:96)
        at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:84)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceBuilder.injector(GuiceInjectorBuilder.scala:181)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder.build(GuiceApplicationBuilder.scala:123)
        at play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationLoader.load(GuiceApplicationLoader.scala:21)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:151)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$3.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:148)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$2.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:148)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$2.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:124)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:124)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:122)
        at scala.util.Success.flatMap(Try.scala:231)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:122)
        at play.core.server.LagomReloadableDevServerStart$$anonfun$mainDev$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$get$1.apply(LagomReloadableDevServerStart.scala:114)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$RunnableExecuteAction.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1402)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
        at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lightbend.lagom.internal.javadsl.api.broker.TopicFactoryProvider
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 33 more

Stacktrace caused by project target (filesystem path to project is C:\Users\lusp\maisvc\usvcs\actor-impl\target).

[INFO] Service actor-impl listening for HTTP on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:62728
[INFO] (Service started, press enter to stop and go back to the console...)
```

The service doesn't work and the obvious question is whether or not stubbing the service call is not allowed???

**UPDATE**

Made some changes, still got the error, so I put the code up on github to document it more completely https://github.com/tevye/lagom-echo-project-from-scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that You have maven dep problem.
In parent pom.xml you have:

```
 <lagom.version>1.3.0-M1</lagom.version>
```

and this version is used by lagom maven plugin.

On the other hand all your lagom dependencies use version 1.2.1:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
        <artifactId>lagom-javadsl-persistence_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

try changing it to:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
        <artifactId>lagom-javadsl-persistence_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>${lagom.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do it for all other lagom deps.

### UPDATE

Your other problem seems to be 2 persistence providers

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
    <artifactId>lagom-javadsl-persistence-jdbc_2.11</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lightbend.lagom</groupId>
    <artifactId>lagom-javadsl-persistence-cassandra_2.11</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Remove dependency  to: **lagom-javadsl-persistence-jdbc_2.11** from pom(s).xml 
(especially actor-impl/pom.xml)

Also You do no need any of them in  actor-api/pom.xml 
From **com.lightbend.lagom** leave there only **lagom-javadsl-api_2.11**

Comment: Makes sense but did not fully correct the problem. Exception is now different, 'binding to com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.PersistentEntityRegistry was already configured at com.lightbend.lagom.javadsl.persistence.jdbc.JdbcPersistenceModule.configure'. Pom.xml updated in github.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you, that worked. Updating the github (even though there is a separate serialization issue to fix).